# Is $(\Bbb N, \tau)$ a compact topological space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Consider the set of natural numbers $\Bbb N$ endowed with the topology $\tau$ given by $\tau = \{\{1 \},\{2 \},\{1,2 \},\{1,2,3 \},\cdots \}$. Is $(\Bbb N, \tau)$ a compact topological space?

I have tried to proceed by taking an open cover of $\Bbb N$. Since each element in that open cover is an element of $\tau$ and every element of $\tau$ contains at most finitely many elements so there doesn't  exist any finite subcollection of that cover which covers $\Bbb N$. I think this is the reason for which $(\Bbb N, \tau)$ is not compact.

Is my reasoning correct at all? Someone please verify it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand which sets lie in $\tau$.

Comment: If $\{2\}$ is not in there then the pattern is clear.

Comment: I have also confusion in it @Jan Bohr. But  I think it should be continued as $\{\cdots,\{1,2,3,4 \},\{1,2,3,4,5 \}, \cdots  \}$. But I am not sure of that.

Comment: Well if you don't know, then how can we? Surely $\tau=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N},\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\dots\}$ would give a topology.

Comment: And yes, then you're idea is correct: $\mathbb{N} = \{1\} \cup \{1,2\} \cup \{1,2,3\} \cup \dots$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.